# Cannot set the number of password retries in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I did the following to set password restrictions for my users on MariaDB.
`ALTER USER 'User Name' FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 3 PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME 3;`
But I get the following error and cannot do it.
Why is this?

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 3 PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME 3' at line 1
```

Comment: MariaDB does not have the options `FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS` or `PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME`, but MySQL has (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/8.0/en/secure-deployment-user-accounts.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, MariaDB does not have this feature.