# How do I set failed login attempts in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

I'm attempting to configure failed login attempts with MariaDB 10.3.  Using the following query (from mysql docs, hoping mariadb would be very similar):

`ALTER USER 'mariadb_user'@'localhost'  FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 4 PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME UNBOUNDED;`

This returns:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 4 PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME UNBOUNDED' at line 2

Does MariaDB actually support `FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS`? I didn't find anything useful when searching the documentation for relevant keywords.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959280/cannot-set-the-number-of-password-retries-in-mariadb

Comment: Where do you get that from? I've never seen it in MariaDB. I sees it in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-management.html), [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6010.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't supported by MariaDB.

As an alternative, you can use the global system variable [max_password_errors](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_password_errors) which was introduced in MariaDB 10.4.

**Note:** max_password_errors will be ignored for localhost connections (:1, 127.0.0.1)